# ProjectServer 2013 REST APIs with Windows Azure Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to use Project Server 2013 REST APIs with Windows Azure access tokens but getting GeneralSecurityAccessDenied error.

I have register my app in Azure AD on the Management Portal to get client_id, redirectUri.

The permissions to the application are “Office 365 SharePoint Online” and “Windows Azure Active Directory”.
I’m calling the authorization endpoint in the following URL, is this correct?

https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id= &redirect_uri=&resource=https://.sharepoint.com

Then I’m calling token endpoint URL

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token with the following parameters
grant_type is authorization_code
code is “Access Code Returned from the first call”
redirect_uri is <MY URL>
resource is https://<mytestdomain>.sharepoint.com
```

This gives me Access Token and Refresh Token, but when I use the Access Token to do something it gives me the error “GeneralSecurityAccessDenied”

My POST request is

```
https:// <mytestdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects/Add
Authorization is Bearer <Access Token>
Content-Type is application/json;odata=verbose
```

The request body is

```
{ 

  'parameters' : {

     'Name':My Test ',

    'Description': Test Project',

    'Start':'1/28/2015'

  }

}
```

The Error response is follows.

```
{

   "error": {
        "code": "20010, Microsoft.ProjectServer.PJClientCallableException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "GeneralSecurityAccessDenied"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any fixes on this? Did you manage to get it working?